# ElasticSearch scoring / number of doc

Tags: elasticsearch, tf-idf

I have small (max 50 char) keywords stored in text field in ElasticSearch index. I noticed that if I clear the index and add only 1 document, let's say "samsung galaxy", the score when I match the document is like 0.95.

But when I add 500k other docs and I make the same query, the score is like 20. I would like to set a `min_score` for this query because I need a certain level of relevancy.

But as the score is depending of the doc count. I can't set a `min_score` as the number of docs in the index will constantly evolve.

I already looked for solutions like `constant_score` but I need the power of Elastic to give me a score (and not 1 or 0).

1) Does this behavior come from the IDF method or not only from it?

2) Is there a way to keep the current search algorythm (or just without the term frequency) and have always the same score for a query without doc count dependency ? This would allow me to set a `min_score`

Comment: The score is not directly dependent on number of docs, but rather on term frequency in index. You can debug it a little bit more by yourself by adding `explain` parameter to query string. In theory after some amount of docs the score of a document should stabilize. You can read [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/controlling-relevance.html) little bit more. Also there are [other](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/similarity.html) similarity functions you can try. Maybe they fit your scenario better.